# Write Paragraph to a form field in iText7 using C#

Tags: c#, itext7

I need to add a short paragraph to a form field in a pdfDocument using iText7. My working is as following:

```
var pdf = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFileStream), new PdfWriter(outputStream));                    
var doc = new iText.Layout.Document(pdf);
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, false);
IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetAllFormFields();

// i want to do something like this

string p1 = "London";
string p2 = "Istanbul";
string p3 = "Sydney";
Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph(p1);
Paragraph para2 = new Paragraph(p2);
Paragraph para3 = new Paragraph(p3);
doc.Add(para1);
doc.Add(para2);
doc.Add(para3);
fields["IWIProductDetails"].SetValue(doc);

//is this possible?
```

I can't have newline ("\n") in pdf. One possible solution is to add paragraphs. Please guide me if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: its related to jave, but it might give you idea https://www.tutorialspoint.com/itext/itext_adding_areabreak.htm

Comment: Yes. Its a fail. I wanted to put a scenrio with my requirements. Main problem is, how to have a newline in a form field?

Comment: @KJ only u and ur God know what u r talking about.